# Documenting Python imports with doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

I'm using doxygen to document my Python code. That's because most of the code in the project is in C++, and doxygen works great with C++.

I would like to document functions/classes created dynamically in C++ extensions. Docstrings aren't an option in this case (they're created in runtime), so the only way is to document them explicitly after import (which would also make most sense for users). But doxygen doesn't seem to recognize that in Python imported entities become members of the scope. So the question is:

**How do I document imported symbols in Python?**

I tried following the [documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks):

```py
## @package test
#  test module

## foo - before
def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass
## @fn bar
#  bar - after

from ext import baz
## @fn baz
#  baz - imported
```

`foo` and `bar` are documented properly:

[image: output_doc]

...but doxygen reports missing `baz`:

```
./test.py:14: warning: documented symbol 'test::baz' was not declared or defined.
```

I also tried `@var`, but the command being used is not an issue, I believe. So how could I document Python imports? Is it possible?

---

Note: I used the bleeding-edge doxygen 1.8.3.1.

Comment: Well it seems that as test::baz isn't defined as ``def`` then it's fair not to comment it in ``test``.  Wouldn't baz be commented in ``ext::baz`` ? on the right of this page -> there are similar questions which might help.

Comment: As I mentioned, `baz` is defined (or rather constructed) in a `.pyd` and cannot be statically documented. I would like to force documentation of this object on the client-side, where it actually belongs.